# New to python and CS. SQlite, flask

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

I'm new to python and CS so this question might be a bit too easy. Thanks for your help I'm getting an error:

Bad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

### After implementing a new html template and python function:

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register user."""

    session.clear()

    if request.form["name"] == "" or request.form["password"] == "":
        return render_template("apology.html")
    elif request.form["password"] != request.form["confirmation"]:
        return render_template("apology.html")
    hash = pbkdf2_sha256.hash("password")

    do.execute("INSERT INTO finance (name, password) VALUES(:name, :password)",
        name=request.form.get["name"], hash=hash)

    session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]

    return redirect(url_for("index"))
```

---

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Register
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="{{ url_for('register') }}" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" name="confirmation" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Register</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: When enabling [debug mode](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#debug-mode), you should be able to get a more verbose error description.

Answer (score 0):

First you should check if the request type is 'POST', after that you check all the conditions. Do like below to resolve the issue:

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
"""Register user."""

session.clear()
if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.form["name"] == "" or request.form["password"] == "":
        return render_template("apology.html")
    elif request.form["password"] != request.form["confirmation"]:
        return render_template("apology.html")
    hash = pbkdf2_sha256.hash("password")

    do.execute("INSERT INTO finance (name, password) VALUES(:name, :password)",
    name=request.form.get["name"], hash=hash)

    session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]
    return redirect(url_for("index"))

else: 
    // you can render the template to be shown for registration.
```